# Manage two identical servlets via path in AEM by Sling

Tags: java, servlets, aem, sling

I have two projects in the same AEM instance, and in both projects I need the same servlet (I don't want to change selector), but it has to handle different templates.

By deploying both projects, calling their respective resources with the servlet, one answers and the other does not. This is because the same servlet is always called in each case (and therefore does not manage the templates of a project).

So I would like to understand if it is possible to manage the two servlets by adding a control on an array of base path. In this way each project goes into the correct servlet and all the templates are managed.

Example:

```
Current version servlet project A 
@Component(
        service = {Servlet.class},
        property = {
                Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION + "=Menu Servlet",
                SLING_SERVLET_METHODS + "=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_GET,
                SLING_SERVLET_RESOURCE_TYPES + "=" + NameConstants.NT_PAGE,
                SLING_SERVLET_SELECTORS + "=" + "contents",
                SLING_SERVLET_EXTENSIONS + "=json"
        }
)

Current version servlet project B
@Component(
        service = {Servlet.class},
        property = {
                Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION + "=Servlet",
                SLING_SERVLET_METHODS + "=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_GET,
                SLING_SERVLET_RESOURCE_TYPES + "=" + NameConstants.NT_PAGE,
                SLING_SERVLET_SELECTORS + "=" + "contents",
                SLING_SERVLET_EXTENSIONS + "=json"
        }
)

New version servlet project A 
@Component(
        service = {Servlet.class},
        property = {
                Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION + "=Servlet",
                SLING_SERVLET_METHODS + "=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_GET,
                SLING_SERVLET_RESOURCE_TYPES + "=" + NameConstants.NT_PAGE,
                SLING_SERVLET_SELECTORS + "=" + "contents",
                SLING_SERVLET_EXTENSIONS + "=json",
                --> NEW_SELECTOR + "=[/content/progA, /content/experience-fragments/progA]"
        }

New version servlet project B
@Component(
        service = {Servlet.class},
        property = {
                Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION + "=Servlet",
                SLING_SERVLET_METHODS + "=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_GET,
                SLING_SERVLET_RESOURCE_TYPES + "=" + NameConstants.NT_PAGE,
                SLING_SERVLET_SELECTORS + "=" + "contents",
                SLING_SERVLET_EXTENSIONS + "=json",
               --> NEW_SELECTOR + "=[/content/progB,/content/experience-fragments/progB]"
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to just have one servlet and have services / components per project that register with a yet to be created registry? The servlet could than call the registry and things are dealt out there. You know, the good old Hollywood principle: Don't call us, we call you.

Answer (score 2):

you can implement [OptingSevlet interface](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-5/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/servlets/OptingServlet.html) and define the `accepts` method that can decide using some mechanism (e.g. through a request param), whether the current servlet should be used to service the request, if not the request will go to the next candidate servlet.

I would also like to point out this is a rather odd usecase, usually you would want to use non-interfering paths pattern for mounting servlet in different projects. also avoid using unnecessarily wide resource types like `NT_PAGE` or `cq:Page`, this makes the servlet a candidate for all pages in the system and can have a detrimental effect on performance.